# How to import a 3rd party Python library into Bluemix?

Tags: python, ibm-cloud

My Python app needs web.py to run but I'm unable to figure out how to get it up to bluemix. I see no options using `cf push`. I tried to "import web" and added some additional code to my app without success.

When I push my Python app to bluemix without `web.py` it fails (naturally) since it does not have what it needs to run.

I'm sure I'm just missing an import mechanism. Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend that you try out this starter template on GitHub. It is enabled with a deploy to Bluemix button that automatically creates a python runtime and postgress database with Django installed. https://github.com/fe01134/djangobluemix

The project includes the requirements.txt file to ensure you have the right dependencies and also the .settings file to read the database user id and password from VCAP Services.  It also leverages Declared services in the manifest file to create a database service for you.

Here is a YouTube Tutorial on how to deploy Python app on Bluemix https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qIcHQQNUmlE&list=PLvsG7O_a5F2dAjsNp6aRACP6vkqdgsZ33&index=5

Answer (score 4):

The cause for this problem was that I was not correctly telling my Python app the needed configuration information when I pushed it out to Bluemix.

What I ended up having to do was add a `requirements.txt` file and a `Procfile` file into the root directory of my Python application, to draw that connection between my Python app and the needed libraries/packages.

In the `requirements.txt` file I specified the library packages needed by my Python app. These are the file contents:

> web.py==0.37
>   wsgiref==0.1.2

where `web.py==0.37` is the version of the **web.py** library that will be downloaded, and `wsgiref==0.1.2` is the version of the web server gateway interface that is needed by the version of **web.py** I am using.

My `Procfile` contains the following information:

> web: python .py $PORT

where `myappname` is the name of my Python app, and `$PORT` is the port number that my Python app uses to receive requests.

I found out too that `$PORT` is optional because when I did not specify `$PORT` my app ran with the port number under the `VCAP_APP_PORT` environment variable for my app.

From there it was just a matter of pushing my app out to Bluemix again only this time it ran fine.

Answer (score 0):

just use pip freeze

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

add the requirements.txt to your project 
when deployed it will automaticly install the dependency